# OnClickListener for each cell in a tableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I have a tablelayout which is of size 3X3 as shown in the image below[image: table layout with 9 cells].

Each cell consist of an imageview. I tried to use onClickListener for individual images but I think it is not a very smart way to do it. If you have any solution to do it in a bit simpler way then I would like to kindly request you for your ideas. I also need to operlay a transparent layer to the imageview when the image view is selected.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

you can make onClickListener for convertview on your adaptor for a gridview

```
>  public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
>      private Context mContext;  
>       
>      // Gets the context so it can be used later  
>      public GridAdapter(Context c) {  
>       mContext = c;  
>      }  
>       
>      // Total number of things contained within the adapter  
>      public int getCount() {  
>       return imagesUrlArray size or what you use here;  
>      }  
>       
> 
>      public Object getItem(int position) {  
>       return null;  
>      }  
>       
>       
>      public long getItemId(int position) {  
>       return position;  
>      }  
>       
>      public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
> 
>  if (convertview == null) {
>             convertview = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutRes, null);
              // your xml cell here
>             holder = new ViewHolder(convertview);
>             convertview.setTag(holder);
>         } else {
>             holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
>         } 
>     
>       holder.image.setImageBitmap(...) or what did yuu use Image adapter ... convertview.setOnclickListener....{do your job here}
> 
>       return convertview;  
>      }  
>     }
```

On activity:

yourGridview defined on xml instead of tableLayout`.setAdapter(GridAdapter);`

Comment: How would you exactly do that ? Can you put a code ?

Comment: I have already found a solution which is totally different than what you suggested. So I am not accepting this as answer. Anyway thank you for answering.